# ctags for shell scripts without extensions

Tags: bash, vim, file-extension, ctags

I'm working on a Bash script that is designed to be run 'as a tool' so has a name without an extension and a `#!/usr/bin/bash` line at the top.

My script has a number of functions, so it would be nice if I could use Vim's tagging support to jump around the code, but I can't get ctags to tag the file. `ctags mytool` produces a tags file that is blank except for the comment section at the top.

If I rename my file to mytool.sh, `ctags mytool.sh` works perfectly.

Is there a way to force ctags to tag a file without an extension?  I've tried a number of options that I found in the [ctags manual](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/ctags.html#OPTIONS) that seem to relate to file extensions, but without joy.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you're using "[Exuberant Ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/)", you can use the `--language-force` option:

```
ctags --language-force=sh mytool
```

This is documented explicitly in the man page.

Answer (score 3):

I use the below command to create the tags file on all files in my entire shell source directory tree

```
ctags -R --language-force=sh
```